GLMM logistic regression with interactions
I have been working on a mixed effects logistic regression model to analyze some data, and I'm seeking some clarification on interpreting the results, particularly when incorporating interaction terms.
I have two models:
Without interaction:
M1 <- glmer(
  cbind(Total_Infected, Total_No_Infected) ~ Treatment + Strain + Days + 
    (1|Plant), 
  family = binomial, 
  data = Datos_OBJT2
) 

With interaction:
M2 <- glmer(
  cbind(Total_Infected, Total_No_Infected) ~ Treatment + Strain * Days + 
    (1|Plant), 
  family = binomial, 
  data = Datos_OBJT2
) 

My main concern arises from the differences in the estimates between the two models, especially regarding the interaction terms. Specifically, I would like to understand how to interpret the estimates and their significance, particularly in the presence of interaction effects.
Could someone kindly explain how to interpret the estimates in Model M2, especially the interaction terms, and how they differ from the estimates in Model M1? Additionally, any insights into the implications of these differences for understanding the relationships between the variables would be greatly appreciated.
Summary of both models
>Summary(M1)
    
               Estimate  Std. Error z value P value
(Intercept)        -6,34    0,25    -25,52  0,00
Treatmentyoung      0,94    0,08    12,43   0,00
StrainB             1,23    0,21    5,87    0,00
StrainC             2,11    0,19    10,81   0,00
StrainD             1,55    0,20    7,68    0,00
StrainE             2,15    0,19    11,04   0,00
StrainF             1,14    0,21    5,34    0,00
as.factor(Days)20   0,82    0,10    8,21    0,00
as.factor(Days)30   0,76    0,10    7,50    0,00


>Summary(M2)

                        Estimate Std.Error z value  P Value
(Intercept)                 -7,44   0,66   -11,25   0,00
Treatmentyoung               0,93   0,08    1,23    0,00
StrainB                      3,02   0,65    4,64    0,00
StrainC                      3,54   0,64    5,53    0,00
StrainD                      1,92   0,68    2,82    0,00
StrainE                      2,67   0,65    4,09    0,00
StrainF                      2,18   0,68    3,21    0,00
as.factor(Days)20            1,24   0,73    1,70    0,09
as.factor(Days)30            2,30   0,66    3,49    0,00
GroupsGroup 2                0,13   0,30    0,42    0,67
StrainB:as.factor(Days)20   -1,62   0,78    -2,09   0,04
StrainC:as.factor(Days)20   -0,91   0,75    -1,21   0,23
StrainD:as.factor(Days)20    0,49   0,79    0,62    0,53
StrainE:as.factor(Days)20    0,23   0,76    0,31    0,76
StrainF:as.factor(Days)20   -0,48   0,79    -0,61   0,54
StrainB:as.factor(Days)30   -2,35   0,70    -3,37   0,00
StrainC:as.factor(Days)30   -2,05   0,68    -3,01   0,00
StrainD:as.factor(Days)30   -0,93   0,72    -1,29   0,20
StrainE:as.factor(Days)30   -1,00   0,69    -1,44   0,15



Have you considered plotting predictions across days (perhaps without the random effect, or for some specific plant)? That would likely tell you a lot already.

I had considered that; however, the issue is that these are measures taken within the same plant, so I can't remove the random effect. Furthermore, there's variation between one plant and another, making it challenging to try to predict with just one plant. Therefore, I need to analyze my entire dataset.

Without the random effects, you'd still be able to see a lot about what's going on. Sure, this is for an average Plant (average in the sense of random effect=0), but you're assuming everything is just some random pertubation around that, so it should be useful enough to look at this. In particular, it may clarify exatly the questions you may have about coefficients & how the change with interactions, because you'd see how the interactions result in different trends across days (or maybe similar & just described differently by "distributing information" across coefficients for different terms).
